# JavaFX8 -fx-background-image doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx-8

I want to set background image of root-pane. For this purpose, I add this inline style to root-pane.

```
-fx-background-image: url("image.png");
```

Image is in same directory as FXML file. I checked path at least 10 times.
Can somebody say, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inline style for fxml. There is a discussion here :

```
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2595120?start=0&tstart=0
```

Please pay attention James_D's answer.

By the way, if you use external css file, your code will work. Please try 'styleclass' property in root tag.